# Program to read 2 integers and print them in while loop gives range_error

Tags: c++

From `Programming: principals and practices` Chapter 4 Drill 1:

**Write a program that consists of a while-loop that (each time around the 
loop) reads in two `int`s and then prints them. Exit the program when a 
terminating `'I'` is entered.**

So far the code's been crashing. When I debug it looks like it is crashed at line 20 with a `range_error`. I looked that up and it said it's because it's trying to access something that doesn't exist.

Also the `|` code is saying that `no conversion from 'const char *' to 'int'` How could I take that symbol in as an `int` so it can terminate? I thought doing it like `(char)x` was right!

Please if you have a solution keep it simple as I'm only on chapter 4 and I just learned loops and vectors.

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    vector<int> tuggo;

    cout << "Enter two ints:" << endl;
    cout << "Enter a | to terminate program instead.";

    while(cin>>x)
    {
        if ((char)x == "|")
            break;
        tuggo.push_back(x);
            if (tuggo.size() == 1)
            {
                cout << tuggo[0] << tuggo[1] << endl;
                keep_window_open();
                break;
            }
            else if (tuggo.size() < 1)
                cout << "Too much data, this crappy program only can handle two integers." << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get used to zero-based indexing.

`size()` is the number of elements. The first element is index 0. So when `size()` is 1, you can only access element 0.

Index 1 is the 2nd element, and so on.

Regarding your `no conversion from 'const char *' to 'int'` error, you should look up char and string literals. `'x'` is of type `char` (a simple numeric value), whereas `"x"` is `const char*` (a pointer to zero or more null-terminated characters). Just change to single quotes, and you won't need the cast either.

Comment: mmm yeah I forgot you don't define chars like that!

Answer (score 5):

When your vector size is 1 you try to access 2 elements - that's your range exception.

Comment: Hrm, the way I wrote it I thought that it wouldn't try to access the elements unless vector has a least 2 elements in it. Doe's size() not start at 0?

Comment: @user2442335 No, why would it? `size` is exactly what it says.

Comment: @user2442335 No. `size()` returns the number of elements, not the maximum index. Example: When `tuggo.size()` is `3`, valid accesses are `tuggo[0]`, `tuggo[1]` and `tuggo[2]`.

Answer (score 2):

`tuggo.size() == 1` means that there is only one element in your `std::vector` (tuggo[0]) try  with `tuggo.size() == 2`